# Calling webservice results in error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, android, vb.net, xamarin

I call a specific `webservice` method from my android phone app and it always results in the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I call MANY different methods in this service with no problem, this is the only one that gives me an issue and I cannot track it down.  The `webservice` is written in `VB.NET`, the phone app `C#`.  Breakpoints confirm that all the data is being passed correctly, there is `NO null` data.

I created a `"log"` system where I can log messages to my database at certain places in my code.  The messages are logged in the database, but the method, apparently, errors out on a call to a function within the method.  I setup the webservice to be able to test it in the production environment remotely and it works EVERYTIME, yet when I call it from my phone app, I get the error.  I'm stumped.  This is the error message I get:

> Source: System.Web.Services Description:Server was unable to process
>   request. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Target
>   Site:System.Object[]  ReceiveResponse(System.Net.WebResponse, 
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientMessage, 
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapExtension[]) Call Stack: at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReceiveResponse 
>   (System.Net.WebResponse response, 
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientMessage message,
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapExtension[] extensions) [0x001ed] in
>   <6f5d26adf5754fd8a1fe9ebdbdc88f48>:0 at 
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke 
>   (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x000ad] in
>   <6f5d26adf5754fd8a1fe9ebdbdc88f48>:0 at
>   MyAndroidApp.DataInterfaceWeb.DataInterface.ProcessSubscription 
>   (System.String list1, System.String list2, System.String list3,
>   System.String list4, System.String list5, System.String list6,
>   System.String list7, System.String list8, System.String list9,
>   System.String list10, System.String list11, System.String list12,
>   System.String list13, System.String list14, System.String list15,
>   System.String list16, System.String list17, System.String list18,
>   System.String list19)   [0x00001] in
>   C:\Users\HP\source\repos\Projects\MyAndroidApp\MyAndroidApp\Web
>   References\DataInterfaceWeb\Reference.cs:2308 at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   MyAndroidApp.DataInterfaceWeb.DataInterface.ProcessSubscription(string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string)
>   at MyAndroidApp.Subscription+<>c__DisplayClass24_0.b__1 (System.Object
>   sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x001ee] in
>   C:\Users\HP\source\repos\Projects\MyAndroidApp\MyAndroidApp\Subscription.cs:211

This is the Web method:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function ProcessSubscription(ByVal list1 As String, ByVal list2 As String,
                               ByVal list3 As String, ByVal list4 As String,
                               ByVal list5 As String, ByVal list6 As String,
                               ByVal list7 As String, ByVal list8 As String,
                               ByVal list9 As String, ByVal list10 As String,
                               ByVal list11 As String, ByVal list12 As String,
                               ByVal list13 As String, ByVal list14 As String,
                               ByVal list15 As String, ByVal list16 As String,
                               ByVal list17 As String, list18 As String, list19 As String) As String
    Dim LogErrors As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LOG")
    Dim MyResponse As ANetApiResponse
    If LogErrors = "TRUE" Then
        LogError("Processing Subscription") '<-- this line is executed as this message appears in the database
    End If
    Try
        Dim amount As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(list16)
        ' I believe that this is the call that causes the error, yet calling 
        ' the method directly via the browser works every time!  Just won't
        ' work when I call the method from the android app.
        MyResponse = ChargeCreditCard.Run(amount.ToString, list11, list12, list19, list3, list4, list6, list7, list8, list9)
    Catch ex As Exception
        LogError(ex.Message) ' <--- never hits this line as nothing is logged after the "Processing subscription" log message
    End Try
    Dim returnmessage As String
    If MyResponse.messages.resultCode = messageTypeEnum.Ok Then
        returnmessage = "SUCCESSFUL"
        PaySubFee(list1, list2, list13)
    Else
        returnmessage = "The card was declined: " & "Error Code: " & MyResponse.messages.message(0).code
    End If

    Return returnmessage 'MyResponse.messages.resultCode ' 0 = ok, 1 = error

    Return result
End Function
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you actually able to utilize the debugger to check what's null. It's always relatively easy to fix a nullref once you actually know what's null, and the best way to find that is by debugging.

Comment: Breakpoints confirm that NOTHING is null.  If you read the question you will see that the method executes as designed when accessed remotely with a browser, yet when I call it with the android app, the method is partially executed and I get the above mentioned error.

Comment: The idea was to breakpoint with the android execution path, which is clearly different than executing from the browser. Something clearly is null based on the exception being thrown.

Comment: Exactly what I do, NOTHING is null.

Comment: @Anu6is ... and logging confirms that the data is passed successfully and that nothing is null.

Comment: Eyeballing the code, the only thing I would think could potentially be null is `MyResponse` although there is no reason for it to be via android only. I suppose you could throw that section in a try catch as well.

Comment: I put in a test for `If MyResponse IsNot Nothing` and you are exactly right, `MyResponse` is null.  Damn ... now why is that happening!  Geese .... this is very frustrating, there is no difference between the browser call, other than its a browser, and the android call.

Comment: I guess take a look at what values are different for these parameters `ChargeCreditCard.Run(amount.ToString, list11, list12, list19, list3, list4, list6, list7, list8, list9)` between the browser and the app. Maybe something unexpected is being included or excluded.

Comment: I've verified that the data is the same on both interfaces.  I write the data to the log, I just didn't want to post that here, and it's correct on both interfaces.  I'm stumped.

Comment: I'm adding some logging to the ChargeCreditCard.Run function.  Hopefully I can get a look at what is going on in there.  I have a `try ... catch`, but nothing is logged so I assume there's no error.  If the call to Authorize.NET is returning NULL, then I'll have to contact them to see why.

Comment: Alright, good luck!

Comment: Yeah, the call to the Authorize.NET via the browser interface to the webservice always returns data, the call via the android app's call to the webservice always causes the call to Authorize.NET to return null.  Gonna have to contact them.

Comment: @Anu6is  Authorize.NET's support was anything but helpful.  After "reviewing" my case they decided that because I was not interacting with their systm, that it wasn't there problem.  You can imagine my reaction ... lol ... in any event I resolved the issue, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days and hours on end of testing I was able to resolve the issue.  I am rather new at developing android apps, so certain things tend to stick in my mind and one of those things is that android for some reason tends to add an extra space, albeit randomly it seems, and depending on the situation, it can cause problems.  On a whim I decided to trim ALL the data that was being transmitted on the call to the webservice and it immediately began working as designed.  A review of my logs did not reveal any extra spaces in the data, but none the less that appears to be the case here.  No where in Authorize.NET's support documentation or forums is there any mention that extra spaces would cause issues, but it does.  If there is leading (or trailing?) spaces in the transaction submitted, `controller.GetApiResponse()` WILL (apparently) return a null response.  Hopefully this will help someone else who is experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

No anyone could help you in this particular error without code and troubleshooting it! This error  when happening that there is an object which is not initialized correctly most of the time.